# Could machines survive in the galactic center?

Tags: survival, robots, galactic, macroengineering, macrolife

Let's say a super advanced robot "species" that are programmed to roam the galaxy and explore. They build gigantic structures similar to Dyson spheres, and  ensure that they will survive to the end of the universe. Now, galactic center is packed with stars that are only light days from each other-Wouldn't be a good place for organic life (because of many reasons) but would it be a good place for machines like Giant spaceships, dyson spheres, any robots ? So many stars means a lot of energy -and if their goal is to take as much energy as possible , I wonder if it could be the best habitat for them- especially if they create more and more copies of themselves (thus- more energy needed).

However, I am aware of the solar flares, supernovas and other stuff that can potentially destroy not only organic life but electronics as well.So,the question: Could machines survive in the galactic center ?

Comment: I could not say whether or not it would be a *good* place for such machines, but technology produced by such an advanced civilization could most certainly survive

Comment: I can't think of a reason that properly shielded electronics, much less photonics or other artificially logic circuits, would have issues in that environment. They'd want to avoid the more crowded sections for collision reasons, and blue supergiants will have a minimum safe distance, but other than that, I think they'd be fine.

Comment: Cooling might be a problem, when massive stars and supernovas throw out massive amounts of dust. Of course it's usually rarefied, not going to clog the radiators, but dust reflects the heat and lowers radiator efficiency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, **your machines wouldn't be at the exact center of the galaxy because that where a supermassive black hole is.** It doesn't matter how good your technology is, nothing will survive that.

But if you're talking about around the center, the density of stars isn't that big an issue. Here's the thing: **light days are still really far apart.** To put it in context, we're only 8 light *minutes* away from our sun, and we're not dying from solar flares.

So as long as your machines aren't trying to live in a black hole, they should have no problem surviving. If they are trying to get energy, the distances between stars are still really big, but they will manage no worse than in any other part of the galaxy.

Comment: Even if they only live outside the black hole, it is fantastic for extremely high velocity launches by gravitational assist and many other uses.

Comment: Light days are not a problem for solar flares, but a super nova can destroy everything withing many light years.  At that star density, there will be plenty of very dangerous stars too close for comfort.